# Id parsing error in Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have edit servlet. Parsing error is only the problem while editing. Even though I have been trying since a half of month I am not able to solve.Please help me

```
package com.intermediateDemo.home.controller;

import com.intermediateDemo.home.dao.ItemDao;
import com.intermediateDemo.home.dao.ItemDaoFactory;
import com.intermediateDemo.home.dto.ItemBean;
import com.intermediateDemo.login.dto.LoginBean;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.IOException;


public class EditExpense extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws NumberFormatException, ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            ItemBean item = new ItemBean();
            ItemDao dao = ItemDaoFactory.getItemDao();
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            LoginBean user = (LoginBean) session.getAttribute("user");
            item.setId(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")));
            item.setItemName(request.getParameter("itemname"));
            item.setItemPrice(Double.valueOf(request.getParameter("itemprice")));
            item.setTransactionTime(request.getParameter("transactiontime"));
            item.setEmail(user.getEmail());
            System.out.println("at edit servlet" +item);
            dao.updateexpense(item, user);

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            response.sendRedirect("homeservlet");
        }


    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher view;
        view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/home/editexpense.jsp");
        view.forward(request,response);
    }
}
```

and jsp to take inpute is

```jsp
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<html>
<head>
<title>editing</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:include page="../includes/header.jsp"/>
<div id="content" style="margin-left: 330px;margin-bottom: 10px">

<form action="/edit" method="post">
    <table style="padding-left: 200px;margin-top: 10px;border: 1px">
        <tr><td>Expense title</td><td style="background-color: limegreen">
            <input name="itemname" type="text" required="required"/></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Expense amount</td><td style="background-color: limegreen">
            <input name="itemprice" type="text" required="required"/> </td></tr>

        <tr><td>Expense date</td><td style="background-color: limegreen;border-bottom-color: limegreen">
            <input name="transactiontime" type="date" id="datepicker" required="required"/></td></tr>

        <%--Hidden field for id--%>

        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${item.id}">

        <tr><td> </td><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="update"/></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
</div>

<jsp:include page="../includes/footer.jsp"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**and error after edited at console is found as below instead of any change.But while deleting delete servlet has no id's integer parsing error at the same way**

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at com.intermediateDemo.home.controller.EditExpense.doPost(EditExpense.java:27)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:394)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

**my updated class is**

```
package com.intermediateDemo.home.controller;

import com.intermediateDemo.home.dao.ItemDao;
import com.intermediateDemo.home.dao.ItemDaoFactory;
import com.intermediateDemo.home.dto.ItemBean;
import com.intermediateDemo.login.dto.LoginBean;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;


public class EditExpense extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws NumberFormatException, ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            ItemBean item = new ItemBean();
            ItemDao dao = ItemDaoFactory.getItemDao();
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            LoginBean user = (LoginBean) session.getAttribute("user");
            item.setId(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")));
            item.setItemName(request.getParameter("itemname"));
            item.setItemPrice(Double.valueOf(request.getParameter("itemprice")));
            item.setTransactionTime(request.getParameter("transactiontime"));
            item.setEmail(user.getEmail());
            System.out.println("at edit servlet" +item);
            dao.updateexpense(item, user);

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            response.sendRedirect("homeservlet");
        }
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher view;
        try {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            LoginBean user = (LoginBean) session.getAttribute("user");
            ItemDao dao = ItemDaoFactory.getItemDao();
            List<ItemBean> item =  dao.getItemFromdb(user);
            request.setAttribute("item", item);
            System.out.println("@ edit servlet ");
            for(ItemBean item1:item){
                System.out.println(item1.getId());
                System.out.println(item1.getTransactionTime());
                System.out.println(item1.getItemPrice());
                System.out.println(item1.getItemName());
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/home/editexpense.jsp");
        view.forward(request,response);
    }
}
```

**stack trace error is**

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from  fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page   /home/editexpense.jsp at line 30

27:                 <input name="transactiontime" type="date" id="datepicker"    required="required" /></td></tr>
28: 
29:             <%--Hidden field for id--%>
30:            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${item.id}">
31: 
32: 
33:             <tr><td> </td><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="update"/>  </td></tr>


Stacktrace:
   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:553)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:457)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
com.intermediateDemo.home.controller.EditExpense.doGet(EditExpense.java:65)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"
java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
javax.el.ListELResolver.coerce(ListELResolver.java:174)
javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:52)
javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:985)
org.apache.jsp.home.editexpense_jsp._jspService(editexpense_jsp.java:80)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
com.intermediateDemo.home.controller.EditExpense.doGet(EditExpense.java:65)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.11 logs.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your id input is empty and your trying to convert empty string to Int. that's why you are getting:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

You are suppose to set request attribute item in your doGet method:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

   RequestDispatcher view;
   //not sure where are you getting your item from. DB??
   request.setAttribute("item", item);
   view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/home/editexpense.jsp");
   view.forward(request,response);
}
```

**Update**
If you want to display a list of item, you need to loop through the list in your jsp. Something like this:

```
  <table style="padding-left: 200px;margin-top: 10px;border: 1px">
    <tr>
     <th>Expense title</th>
     <th>Expense amount</th>
     <th>Expense date</th>
     <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${item}" var="it">
    //the form should be after the for loop
    <form action="/edit" method="post">
    <tr>
     <td><input name="itemname" type="text" required="required" value="it.id"/></td>
     <td><input name="itemprice" type="text" required="required" value="it.itemPrice" />     </td>
     <td><input name="transactiontime" type="date" id="datepicker" required="required" value="it.transactionTime"/></td>
     <td>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${it.id}">
     </td>
    </tr>
   //closing from tag
    </form>
  </c:forEach>
 </table>
```

Comment: @Sasvathan I did as you have suggested above but while editing the folowing error comes `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /home/editexpense.jsp at line 32

29: 
30:             <%--Hidden field for id--%>
31: 
32:             <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${item.id}">
33: 
34:             <tr><td> </td><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="update"/></td></tr>
35:         </table>`

Comment: can you post the full stack trace on ur post?? also can you post your updated class too??

Comment: You are returning a list of item, thus you need to loop through the list to display it. Look at my updated post.

Comment: I have been doing those things just for the edit operation but not for the display

Comment: yea, but if you want to edit the list item item.You do exact same thing, except you include each row in a form. So every time user click a edit button on column, it will send a post request to the backend.

Comment: but not wording edit operation for other rows which have not zero id

Comment: My bad, the form should be after the foreach loop and also don't forgot to close the form tag. I updated my code, take a look

Answer (score 0):

The expression langauge (EL) `${item.id}` is evaluated to empty string. That means that the item's `id` is `null`.

You can do two things:

- Make sure that `item` exists in the scope (`pageScope`, `requestScope`, `sessionScope`...) that you want.
- Use a default value.

  ```
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${not empty item.id ? item.id : '0' }">
  ```

Comment: let me try @Paul Vargas as u have suggested.

Comment: @user3620849 Q: `dao.getItemFromdb(user)` return only one element (item) in the list?

Comment: as I saw in console item contain all value.But what should I do then